# Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE ) for the Gaussian-noise simple linear regression model

Tags: statistics, closed-form, regression, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I am reviewing the method of maximum likelihood  and I was looking at the Gaussian-noise simple linear regression model at this [link](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf). I understand up to equation (3) on page 2. I assumed it followed by finding MLE parameters using derivative with respect to $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\sigma^2}$. 
When I tried to solve this myslef I obtained the $\hat{\beta_1}$ and $\hat{\beta_2}$ as follows:

$\hat{\beta}_0 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i - \hat{\beta}_{1}x_i}{n}=\bar{y}-{\hat{\beta}_1}\bar{x}$

$\hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i - \hat{\beta}_{0}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2}$ or

$\bar{xy} - \hat{\beta_0}\bar{x} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{x^2} =0$

I don't understand how the closed form solution shown below is obtained:

$\hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{c_{xy}}{{s_x^2}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^2} $ (written in equation 4)

Can anyone help to clarify this please?

Comment: Just solve the system of linear equation to get $\hat\beta_1=\dfrac{\overline{xy}-\overline x\,\overline y}{\overline{x^2}-{\overline x}^2}$ and then try to transform this expression into equation 4.

Comment: The document you attach is about least squares, not MLE.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan  Thanks for your response, I still cannot figure it out. when I put $\hat{\beta}_0$ in $\hat{\beta}_1$ I don't obtain any useful equation.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks for the comment, I changed the link to match my explanation.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan I was wrong. The equation you wrote works, just I need to find out how transform it to equation 4.